# angular2 quick-start without using lite-server

Tags: angularjs

My quick-start runs fine with default installation .

however, I don't want to use lite-server since I have already got node.js installed.

Is there anyway to change the package.json command to start node rather than lite-server?

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
```

I changed from

```
"lite": "lite-server",
```

to

```
"lite": "node",
```

node started with no error. But when I tried localhost:3000 the browser gave "unable to connect". Any idea?
I also want to remove lite server from under node_modules as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure.

`"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"node your/folder/app.js\" ",`

Comment: i  disagree. he asked "Is there anyway to change the package.json command to start node rather than lite-server?" i showed the line of the package.json that does what he asks to do.

Answer (score 0):

in `package.json`, replace 
`"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "` with `"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "`