# node (angular 2) updates the input field even on different PC or browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have an angular 2 application with a login page. I am opening this page on different PCs. If i insert a value in the username field, say "**pippo**", the page on the other PC reflects the change, so I also see "**pippo**" on there!! Seems a chat !
I have no idea of how this is possible, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Excerpt from the login page:

```
<div class="login_fields">
    <label>Username</label>
    <div><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"/></div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might be using [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, i see "Connected to BrowserSync" notification on top right angle during page loading. I have not added it intentionally. In fact i have simply followed the "Quick start" and "Tour of heroes" tutorial. I am googling for how to remove it. Thanks again. I will let you know if this solves my problem

Comment: That happens when "Getting starteds" include 170 Mbyte of dependencies and do not tell us noobs, what these are all for :D

Comment: @MA-Maddin: yeah :(

Comment: @Puigcerber - i am trying to follow the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584451/angular2-quick-start-without-using-lite-server